# conditional validation depending on 2 elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using jquery validation I have used the .addMethod to add a regular expression.   I also have a rule if a checkbox is not checked, then it will require the element be filled out as well as comply with the regex.

noPreviousEmployers is the id of the checkbox  that if checked it should not display any validation messages, if it is not checked then it will display the required message and if it has data in the input it should run the regex

```
    $.validator.addMethod("regex", function (value, element, regexpr) {
       return regexpr.test(value);
    }, "");


rules:{
    EndSalary1:{
        required: '#noPreviousEmployers:unchecked', 
        regex: /^\$?[0-9]{1,3}(\,?\d{3})?(\,?\d{3})?(\.[0-9]{2})?$/
    }

},
messages:{  
    EndSalary1:{
         required: "Required Field", 
         regex: "Format As US Currency"
    }    
}
```

I have even tried with this

```
$.validator.addMethod("regex", function (value, element, regexpr) {
    if(value.length != 0){
        return regexpr.test(value);
    }
}, "");
```

when I test with the checkbox checked and no data in the field it will  display the message for regex validation.  It should not display anything in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to write a custom rule for any new `regex` patterns.  There is already a default rule built into [the `additional-methods.js` file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.0/dist/additional-methods.js) called `pattern` that takes a regex as its parameter.

```
rules:{
    EndSalary1:{
        required: '#noPreviousEmployers:unchecked', 
        pattern: /^\$?[0-9]{1,3}(\,?\d{3})?(\,?\d{3})?(\.[0-9]{2})?$/
    }
}
```

**DEMO**:  [jsfiddle.net/mrf5ja4d/](https://jsfiddle.net/mrf5ja4d/)

Comment: Odd because there are many many many many places on the web including on Stack Overflow where people will tell you to do the required parameter the way i have done, and it does work.   Try it some time.      I had forgotten to add the additional-methods.js file

Comment: from the documentation for jquery validation  https://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/    go to the 5th example.

Comment: @Miranda, you are correct.  Updated answer accordingly.